# Do I underestimate the power of NumPy.. again?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I don't think I can optimize my function anymore, but it won't be my first time that I underestimate the power of NumPy.

Given:

- 2 rank NumPy array with coordinates
- 1 rank NumPy array with elevation of each coordinate
- Pandas DataFrame with stations

Function:

```
def Function(xy_coord):
    # Apply a KDTree search for (and select) 8 nearest stations
    dist_tree_real, ix_tree_real = tree.query(xy_coord, k=8, eps=0, p=1)
    df_sel = df.ix[ix_tree_real]        

    # Fits multi-linear regression to find coefficients
    M = np.vstack((np.ones(len(df_sel['POINT_X'])),df_sel['POINT_X'], df_sel['POINT_Y'],df_sel['Elev'])).T
    b1,b2,b3 = np.linalg.lstsq(M,df_sel['TEMP'])[0][1:4]

    # Compute IDW using the coefficients
    return sum( (1/dist_tree_real)**2)**-1 * sum((df_sel['TEMP'] + (b1*(xy_coord[0] - df_sel['POINT_X'])) + 
                                                  (b2*(xy_coord[1]-df_sel['POINT_Y'])) + (b3*(dem[index]-df_sel['Elev']))) * 
                                             (1/dist_tree_real)**2)
```

And I apply the function on the coordinates as follow:

```
for index, coord in enumerate(xy):    
    outarr[index] = func(coord)
```

This is an iterative process, if I try this `outarr = np.vectorize(func)(xy)` then Python crashes, so I guess that's something I should avoid doing.

I also prepared an IPython Notebook, so I could write LaTeX, something I've always dreamed of doing for a long time. Till now. The day has come. [Yeah](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mattijn/pynotebook/blob/master/ipynotebooks/Untitled11.ipynb)

---

Off topic: the math won't show up in the nbviewer.. on my local machine it looks like this:

[image: LaTeX in my local IPython working]

Comment: You can query an array of points when calling `tree.query`, so there is no need to use a for loop.

Comment: Wow, that's new for me, let me try it. Thanks

Comment: On a side note, IDW is almost always a terrible choice for interpolation.  It implicitly makes a lot of unrealistic assumptions.  It assumes that all of your observed points were a local minimums or maximums and that the interpolated surface should radially decay to the mean of the data away from the observed points.  There are rare cases where those are good assumptions, but it's usually a poor choice.  A radial basis function is probably a better choice in this case. Or, as you appear to be using elevation to predict temperature, use something more complex, such as cokriging.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that's useful information. It's easier to build this from scratch or is it possible to use and customize existing modules?

Comment: @HYRY Now I can query arrays with kdtree, but I'm stuck with how to call the df with the multidimensional index array from kdtree. If you please can show me how the function becomes, would be really appreciated. I guess some sleep will do me good as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggest is don't use DataFrame for the calculation, use numpy array only. Here is the code:

```
dist, idx = tree.query(xy, k=8, eps=0, p=1)
columns = ["POINT_X", "POINT_Y", "Elev", "TEMP"]
px, py, elev, tmp = df[columns].values.T[:, idx, None]
tmp = np.squeeze(tmp)
one = np.ones_like(px)

m = np.concatenate((one, px, py, elev), axis=-1)
mtm = np.einsum("ijx,ijy->ixy", m, m)
mty = np.einsum("ijx,ij->ix", m, tmp)
b1,b2,b3 = np.linalg.solve(mtm, mty)[:, 1:].T

px, py, elev = px.squeeze(), py.squeeze(), elev.squeeze()

b1 = b1[:,None]
b2 = b2[:,None]
b3 = b3[:,None]

rdist = (1/dist)**2
t0 = tmp + b1*(xy[:,0,None]-px) + b2*(xy[:,1,None]-py) + b3*(dem[:,None]-elev)
outarr = (t0*rdist).sum(1) / rdist.sum(1)

print outarr
```

output:

```
[ -499.24287422  -540.28111668  -512.43789349  -589.75389439  -411.65598912
  -233.1779803  -1249.63803291  -232.4924416   -273.3978919   -289.35240473]
```

There are some trick in the code:

1. `np.linalg.solve` in numpy 1.8 is a generalized ufunc that can solve many linear equations by one call, but `lstsq` is not. So I need use `solve` to calculate `lstsq`.
2. To do many matrix multiply by one call, we can't use `dot`, `einsum()` does the trick, but I think it may be slower than `dot`. You can `timeit` for your real data.

Comment: Really amazing what you did. It's so beautiful. The way how you use Numpy, it's not just a tool, it's a philosophy.

Comment: For real data, work what I did with my for loop function: 1 hour 51 minutes, with your code: 3 minutes... Really powerful indeed